# Error using .bind() in React event handler

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, function-binding

I am working through a React tutorial and cannot understand why I am having a bug.

I am attempting to add this button element using React:

`<button onClick={this.add.bind(null, 'new item')}>New Item</button>`

the event handler should call the following function which lies inside a different React class:

```
    add: function(item) {
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr.push(item);
    this.setState({comments: arr});
    },
```

I was told this was not working because I am "binding null to your functions this value and inside the function you are accessing properties from this which results in a typeError (probably: cannot access property state of null or sh.)"

However, I have no idea what this means or how to solve the problem. Please help.

Below is a link to my full codepen project and the youTube tutorial (React JS Tutorials for Beginners - 13 - Creating New Components by theNewBoston) I am using.

http://codepen.io/Daniel_Widrich/pen/yVaXXZ

https://www.youtube.com/watchv=OKRu7i49X54&index=13&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA

Thank you very much in advance.  This is my first question on StackOverflow and I am attempting to get accepted into an apprenticeship program based on this project.  Any feedback is much appreciated and I'm a big boy so I can handle criticism.

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` means that you're calling `bind` on an `undefined` object. ie. `this.add` is `undefined`.

Why is `this.add` undefined?

Because you don't have an `add` function defined in the `Board` component. Move the `add` function from the `Comment` component to the `Board` component.

(Move lines 15-19 of your Javascript code into the `Board` component.)

[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRyjpB)

Comment: Thank you.  I am grateful.  This really comes down to USER ERROR and I will delete the question